# Docker run linked containers after first one has exited

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two containers that I am trying to run using docker-compose.

```
version: '2.1'
volumes:
  settings:

services:
  tester:
    image: download
    volumes:
      - settings:/home/settings
  db:
    image: kartoza/postgis:12.0
    volumes:
      - settings:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
   depends_on:
      tester:
      condition: service_started
  command: bash -c "while ping -c 1 tester &>/dev/null; do sleep 1; done;  && /docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

I have tried the above compose file but I haven't managed to figure out why it is not working. The first container should basically download a SQL file and exit and the DB would then initialize running the SQL file. How can I get this to work.

Comment: Can you paste the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want to wait for is for a specific file to appear in `/docker-entrypoint.d`. So, something like:

```
command: >-
  bash -c "while ! [ -f /docker-entrypoin-initdb.d/somefile.sql ]; do 
  sleep 1; done && /docker-entrypoint.sh"
```

You'll want to make sure that your `download` image doesn't download directly to the target filename, because you run the risk in that case of starting your database service before the file is fully downloaded.  You'll to:

- Download to a temporary filename
- Rename the file when the download is complete

Comment: You will need to add brackets in the [ ! -f /docker-entrypoin-initdb.d/somefile.sql] so that the bash works

Comment: Thanks for catching that typo!